# How to pass multiple-level of C structure between Applicaiton and library

Tags: c, api, sdk, abi

### Application Code:

```
typedef struct B1 {    
       int bparam1;    
       int bparam2;    
       int bparam3; 
    }B1_t;

typedef struct A1 {    
       int version; //version2    
       int param1;    
       int param2;    
       B1_t bparam;    
       char param3;    
       int param4; 
   }A1_t;
```

### Library version1:

```
typedef struct B1
{
   int bparam1;
   int bparam2;
}B1_t;

typedef struct A1
{
   int version; //version1
   int param1;
   int param2;
   B1_t bparam;
   char param3;
   int param4;
}A1_t;
```

I am facing issue when pass A1 struct parameters between my C application when linking with C Library.
My code while running on A1 version1 against the application compiled with A1 version2. I see data is not as expected when library decoding the A1 structure.

Application fill the parameters with version=2 and B1 structure has some new parameters added in version.

When my application which is backward compatible, tries to run on platform version=1, while decoding A1 parameters, param3 & para4 were not as per expected.

Is there any way we can decode the structure between application and library when running on different versions?

Comment: If These objects are defined in a header file, It is possible to create one whenever it's created. Otherwise, It states in source file.

Comment: Compiled my application against version2 of the  library. I pushed my application on to the target device running on version1 of the library. In version1, B1_t structure layout is different. So while printing the value of param3 & param4 -> i see different values to the one passing from application.

Comment: I guess the version 2 library knows how to deal with version 1 data struct for backwards compatibility, but you cannot expect the version 1 library to know how to deal with version 2 data struct. It ought to check the version stored in the data struct and handle it as an error if too high. Some interfaces may allow higher version in the data struct as long as changes are only made after the last member of the previous version of the struct.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for something what android native applications does. How android NDK supports backward compatibility like newer apps able to work on older android platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard does not provide any support for passing objects defined differently in different translation units (such as the translation unit(s) used to compile library modules and the translation unit(s) used to compile application modules).

The methods by which objects are passed as arguments is up to each C implementation and is usually done in accordance with a platform Application Binary Interface (ABI). The ABI may specify that small structures are passed in registers, and it may specify that large structures are written to the stack. If the library expects a parameter of one size and the application passes another, the mismatch between where the library code expects to find the passed arguments and where they actually are can cause a variety of misbehaviors.

In common C implementations, there is no practical way to support passing differently defined versions of structures by value between routines.

A common method of handling versioned data structures is for the application to have no knowledge at all of the data structure’s size or internal members. To create a data structure, the application calls a library routine that allocates memory, initializes a data structure, and returns a pointer to it. To interact with the data structure in any way, the application passes the pointer to various library routines. This can be used to set members (or, more abstractly, state information) in the data structure, to access members (or information), to release the structure when use of it ends, and to perform other functions.

If you do want the application to have more direct access to the structure and to work with it by value rather than via a pointer, there are options. They require attentiveness to specifics of the C standard, to ensure that the behavior remains defined. One approach is to ensure that newer versions of the structures are always supersets of previous versions. Ideally, any previous version of the structure will be the initial member of the new version of the structure, and then this member can be passed to old library routines. Failing that, one can ensure that the old version of the structure is a prefix of the new version of the structure—in the C implementation being used, the layout of the structure is such that its initial bytes form the bytes that represent the old structure. (This alludes to some technical details in the C standard.) When this is ensured, you still cannot pass the new structure by value where the old structure is expected, due to the ABI issues, but you can pass the structure by way of a pointer, and the library can use the pointer to access the bytes that represent the old version of the structure. (For technical reasons, it may be appropriate to do this by copying the bytes into an instantiation of the old structure type. Some old will attempt to do it by converting pointer types, but the resulting behavior is not defined by the C standard.)

The above paragraph is included as a technical possibility, but I do not recommend it. The common solution is to use pointers as described in the earlier paragraph. Searching for “opaque structures” or “opaque pointers” would provide more information.

All of this requires planning in the initial versions of the library so that the interface it publishes is suitable for future upgrading.

Comment: opaque structures” or “opaque pointers” approach looks better solution for my problem. Thanks @Eric for your suggestion